# Extending RepositoryItemWriter does not delete rows so that the next step sees the rows

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am attempting to use a RepositoryItemWriter to delete Products by their Ids using the RepositoryItemWriter as recommended. I have configured a RepositoryItemWriter as follows:

```
 @Repository
 public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product,Long> {
 }
```

Next, I specify a RepositoryItemWriter bean as follows:

```
 class ProductRepositoryItemWriter extends RepositoryItemWriter<Product>{
   private CrudRepository productRepository;
    
    ProductRepositoryItemWriter(CrudRepository productRepository) {
   
    super.setRepository(this.productRepository =                                                      
  productRepository
                                                          
    } 

      @Transactional
      @Override
       protected void doWrite(List<? extends Product> products) {                   
      this.productRepository.deleteAll(products);      
  }
```

}
My step looks like this:

```
public Step processStep(@Qualifier("jpaTransactionManager") final PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("processStep")
            .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager)
            .chunk(120)
            .reader(productJpaItemReader)
            .writer((ItemWriter)productRepositoryWriter)
            .build();
   }
```

I see the deletes occurring but the products are not deleted so that the next step fails to insert the products. That step follows the delete step  like this on("COMPLETED").to("uploadStep).end()

```
@Bean("repopulateFlow")
 Flow repopulateFlow() {
    FlowBuilder<Flow> flowBuilder = new FlowBuilder<>. 
  ("repopulateFlow);
    flowBuilder.start(deleteStep).on("COMPLETED")
            .to(upLoadStep)
            .end();
       return flowBuilder.build();
    }
```

The deleteStep uses my ProductRepositoryItemWriter to delete the rows and then the next step in the flow tries to re-insert the data but that step finds data in the table that the deleteStep should have deleted from the table.  How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

I ran delete step alone in a job and it does not delete the rows in the table after it completes. I use a HikariCP pool using properties that populate a DataSourceProperties object to create the datasource. I wonder if Spring is not setting it to auto-commit true or I need to create a Hikari Pool and then set the auto-commit property to. true.

The uploadStep fails because rows are still there so I get a ConstraintsViolationException.  I removed the @Transactional but still see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `@Transactional` on your `doWrite` method. The writer is already executed in a transaction driven by Spring Batch.

Comment: I removed it.  The real problem is that I thought that when the deleteJob finishes all the rows would have been deleted and so the table would be ready to re-insert the data.  The question is in a flow does the first step in the flow finish entirely before the next step starts?  I ask that because I expect all rows to be deleted before the next step to insert new data to not find any rows but I get a ConstraintsViolationException indicating the batch delete did not empty the table

Comment: `The question is in a flow does the first step in the flow finish entirely before the next step starts? `: yes, in a sequential flow step2 would start only when step1 is done.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I solved the issue by using a Tasklet. which deletes all the rows so that there is. no overlap. It. seems like. if the flow has a chunked step, the delete for the rows in that chunk get deleted and then the reader reads a new set of data that haven't been deleted and it causes it to fail.